# jQuery ajax jsonp call always get unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsonp

I've been wasting a great deal of time for something I think is so simple, yet there are no good examples that illustrate how and what the ajax call is doing.

This is my javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json',
dataType: 'jsonp',
data: {
    location: myLoc,
    timestamp: myTime,
    sensor: true
},
success: function(){alert('OK');},
error: function(){alert('FAIL');}
})
}
```

The variables "myLoc" and "myTime" are not the problem. In fact if I cut and paste the URI into my browser it works just fine and shows the data: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?callback=jQuery18307430207263678312_1354817349576&location=36.7468422%2C-119.7725868&timestamp=1354817353&sensor=true&_=1354817353398

From what i've been reading, the "callback" parameter is automagically generated and somehow the code should be smart enough to call the success function or error function.

The error that chrome returns is "Uncaught syntax error unexpected token ':'"
The javascript code always calls the error function no matter what I try. I added a jsonpCallback parameter (didn't work), json parameter (didn't work), changed dataType to "json" (didn't work due to cross domain error).

Please help.

Comment: that api doesn't seem to support jsonp in the way you are using it.

Comment: any ideas on how i can get the result into a variable?

Comment: First you have to figure out how to make the api support JSONP if it can support JSONP. Otherwise you'll have to resort to a service such as YQL or a server-side proxy

Comment: And, that API does not support JSONP. it is intended to be requested by your server, not the browser.

Comment: you're right.. the api doesn't support jsonp

Comment: @elvis: I've answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953965/response-from-ajax-call-not-working/38956911#38956911); that approach is [safer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128062/is-this-safe-for-providing-jsonp/3128948#3128948) and more effective than the *JSONP* approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.Stringify({
        location: myLoc,
        timestamp: myTime,
        sensor: true
    }),
    success: function(){alert('OK');},
    error: function(){alert('FAIL');}
});
```