# unexpected token : on ajax call with jsonp dataType

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, cross-domain, jsonp

I'm trying to use the [Readability API](https://www.readability.com/developers/api/parser)

I've this function to make the ajax call with jsonp dataType

```
function getInfo() {
    var getURL = "https://www.readability.com/api/content/v1/parser";

    $.ajax({
        url: getURL,
        type: 'GET',
        crossDomain: true,
        data: { url: url, token: token, callback : "?" },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.content);
            textString = data.content;
        },
        error: function() { alert('Failed!'); }
    });
}
```

This is what I get in return.

[image]

However I also get a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` error along with this and the 'error' case is invoked printing the "failed" alert.

How can I fix the unexpected token?

Comment: based on the [docs](https://www.readability.com/developers/api/parser#idm386426118064) - it seems only the `/confidence` method supports **jsonp** - have you tried **without** the `callback: "?"` in the data - that would be wrong anyway

Comment: I tried with `data: { url: url }` and GET url as `https://readability.com/api/content/v1/confidence` but I get an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery20009139937227591872_1452835074874 is not defined`

Comment: @DelightedD0D - I thought jQuery was majick and when datatype is set to jsonp, it automagically adds `callback=some_big_arse_random_string` to the query and defines `some_big_arse_random_string` function to do the majicks ... you can control what the callback parameter NAME is, but as it is `callback` on that site, there is no need for such shenanigans

Comment: In the ajax call, I added a `jsonpCallback: "generate"` thinking it will act as the callback. In the return string, the `jQuery20009139937227591872_1452835074874` has been replaced with `generate` and I've a `function generate() { //do something; }`. This is also throws up `generate is not defined` error. When trying with `json` type, it throws the `access-control-allow-origin` error.

Comment: @JaromandaX touche, it appears that I misunderstood how that worked as well as the point your were trying to make :)

Comment: @DelightedD0D - why touche? the language I used (majick etc) was not in any way directed at anyone, just describing the I-don't-need-to-think-goodness that is jquery

Comment: @JaromandaX my bad, I read that with a playfully facetious tone that apparently only existed in my mind

Comment: @ptamzz: Please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953965/response-from-ajax-call-not-working/38956911#38956911) on the same challenge you are facing (**unexpected token** on *AJAX* call using *JSONP* and further, **access-control-allow-origin** error) for an effective solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using the approach from my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38956911/6381711) on a similar challenge can help you address effectively the challenge you are facing: **unexpected token** on *AJAX* call using *JSONP*, and further, a **access-control-allow-origin** error.

For [security reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3128948/6381711), I will recommend the [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) implementation over the *JSONP* method.

*Please note: do read read the first two comments below the answer for an encompassing solution.*